# Checking the repeated values and then finding mean

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I m working on my project, where i have 2 images as `Img1` and `Img2`.
As `Img1` is the binary image so i have calculated all decimal values.
For `Img2` i have taken the pixel values.

For convenience i have taken 10X10 matrix values from the entire image for the below operation.

```
[row,col] = size(Img1);
m = zeros(row,col);
w = [1 2 4 8; 16 32 64 128; 256 512 1024 2048; 4096 8192 16384 32768]; 
for i=2:10
    for j=2:10
        O = double(Img1(i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2));
        m(i,j) = sum(sum(O.* w));

    end;
end; 
[row,col] = size(Img2);
 count = row*col;
 outMat = zeros(4,4,count);
l=0;
%m = zeros(row,col);delete
O = zeros(1,256);
for i=2:10
    for j=2:10
         l=l+1;
       outMat(:,:,l) = Img2(i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2);
        vec = outMat(3,3,:);
        vec = vec(:);       
    end;
end;
```

Now, for `Img2` , i have collected all pixel values, and need to store 2 col.as below.

```
Col1        col2 from Img2
from Img1
44128       162
54960       150
58320       119
31200       120
48240       180
54960       160
44128       163
51109       90  
44128       56
```

Here, 44128 is repeated 3 times,now adding all correspong mapping values from col2 i.e. 
162,163,56 add them all divide by 3(becos occurance of 44128 is 3 times) and same procedure
to be followed for all values.

```
44128  (162+163+56)/3
54960  (150+160)/2
58320  (119/1)
31200  (120/1)
48240  (180/1)
51109  (90/1)
```

Here, I want to create an array `N` of 1D 1X(size of col) which acts as a counter of `Img1` decimal 
values,repeated values and store the counter values inside `N`, and then finding mean by dividing corresponding counter values of `N` to the `Img2` pixel values as above.
Please help:-( , how can i write the code further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way doing it using `sparse`.

Accumulate sums and counts:

```
S = sparse(Img1, ones(size(Img1)), Img2);
N = sparse(Img1, ones(size(Img1)), ones(size(Img2)));
```

Determine which values actually occur:

```
ind = find(N)
```

Extract sums and counts for those values:

```
S = full(S(ind))
N = full(N(ind))
```

Compute corresponding means

```
M = S ./ N
```

For your example numbers, this gives

```
ind =

       31200
       44128
       48240
       51109
       54960
       58320

S =

   120
   381
   180
    90
   310
   119


N =

     1
     3
     1
     1
     2
     1


M =

   120
   127
   180
    90
   155
   119
```

Comment: How can write a this inside the above for-loop for determining these mean values?!!

Comment: @STripathy, I'm afraid I don't understand what your code does. As far as I can see, at one point in your code you have the data that you called "Col1        from Img1" and "Col2 from Img2", and at this point you have to insert the code I gave you. Is that `m` and `vec`, or what is it? – I can't tell.

Comment: @ADonda,If you just apply the above code `Img1`(binary Image) and `Img2`(for gray image) you can get the output. Here `m` which store the decimal values like(44128 54960...)  and `vec` which stores the gray values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
totals = sparse(1, Img1, Img2 );
denominators = sparse( 1, Img1, 1);
img1vals = find(totals);
averages = nonzeros(totals) ./ nonzeros(denominators);
[img1vals(:) averages(:)]
```